# ERROR: Can't find variable SSL

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to pick a value from JSON and insert it on a diferents text boxes but it show the value "undefined". The objective is insert link on name space and link space and save it on LocalStorage and some statick values like google and yahoo. Please can someone help me? Thanks you so much.
EDIT: Now is solved, and now dont work the buttons, some one? Please

NEW PROBLEM:The error only appear if I press the buttons (it don't create the buttons).
ERROR: Can't find variable SSL

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>SSL Checker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json.json" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body onLoad="start()">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>SSL Checker</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="data">
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="SSL.Add()">
            <input type="text" id="add-name" placeholder="Name"></input>
            <input type="text" id="add-link" placeholder="Link"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>

        <div id="edit" role="aria-hidden">
            <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="saveEdit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-name">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> <a onclick="CloseInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <p id="counter"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="table">
        <table style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <tr>
                <th>Sites:</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="urls">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

js:

```
    function start() {
var SSL = new function() {
            //List urls to check
            this.el = document.getElementById('urls');

            this.Count = function(data) {
                var el = document.getElementById('counter');
                var name = 'url';

                if (data) {
                    if (data > 1) {
                        name = 'urls';
                    }
                    el.innerHTML = 'There are:' + ' ' + data + ' ' + name;
                } else {
                    el.innerHTML = 'No ' + name;
                }
            };
            //Buttons configuration
            this.FetchAll = ss =function() {
                var data= '';

                if (MyJSON.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < MyJSON.length; i++) {
                        data += '<tr>';
                        data += '<td><a href="' + MyJSON[i].url + '">' + MyJSON[i].name+ '</a></td>';
                        data += '<td><button onclick="SSL.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>';
                        data += '<td><button onclick="SSL.Delete(' + i + ')">Delete</button></td>';
                        data += '</tr>';

                    }
                }

                this.Count(MyJSON.length);
                return this.el.innerHTML = data;
            };
            //Add name
            this.Add = function() {
                el = document.getElementById('add-name');
                el1 = document.getElementById('add-link')
                var url = el.value;
                var url1 = el1.value;
                if (url) {
                    MyJSON.name.push(url.trim());
                    el.value = '';
                    this.FetchAll();
                }
                if (url) {
                    MyJSON.url.push(url1.trim());
                    el1.value = '';
                    this.FetchAll();
            }
            }

            //Edit
            this.Edit = function(item) {
                var el = document.getElementById('edit-name');
                el.value = MyJSON.name[item];
                document.getElementById('edit').style.display = 'block';
                self = this;
                document.getElementById('saveEdit').onsubmit = function() {
                    var url = el.value;
                    if (url) {
                        self.urls.splice(item, 1, url.trim());
                        self.FetchAll();
                        CloseInput();
                    }
                }
            };
            //Delete
            this.Delete = function(item) {
                MyJSON.name.splice(item, 1);
                this.FetchAll();
            };

        }

        SSL.FetchAll();

        function CloseInput() {
            document.getElementById('edit').style.display = 'none';
        }
}
```

Comment: You keep calling `MyJSON.urls` and `MyJSON.links` these are not fields in your `MyJSON` array. You can loop through the array and do `MyJSON[i].name` and `MyJSON[i].url`

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'MyJSON.name[i]')
Now it show's this error.

Comment: Solved but now the buttons dont work :C

Comment: Generating HTML by concatenating strings is not advised.  Better to use DOM methods to create and populate elements and bind event handlers.

Comment: I need to do it like it

Comment: No, you don't "need" to generate your HTML using concatenation.  Not even remotely.  Spend a little time and learn to use the DOM properly.